# How to maintain login session in ios?

Tags: ios, swift

I would like to know where I need to change the root view controller in the app programming. Below is my code

```
class NavigationViewController: UINavigationController {

var window: UIWindow?

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let storyBoard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let newRootView = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "WelcomeViewController") as! WelcomeViewController
    let userStatus = UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "isLoggedIn")
    if userStatus {
        self.window?.rootViewController = newRootView
    }

  }  
}
```

I am setting the value for isLoggedIn key as true when user logged in and false when the user logged out so that I can retrieve the value in this navigation controller subclass, based on that I can choose the root view controller. But its not working fine it remains the same whenever I am launching the app I am getting the login page only though I already logged in, also please don't suggest me to change the root view controller inside of didfinishlaunchingwithoptions method. Could someone help me to solve it? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you checked this on device?

Comment: Simulator is not working properly for UserDefaults

Comment: try to set two segues from storyboard and then perform one of them from code depending on the situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly the goal of your code, you want to boot directly on `WelcomeViewController` if the user is already logged in.

You could try to create a custom segue called `ReplaceSegue` and set this `ReplaceSegue` to the segue linking the `NavigationViewController` and the `ViewController`.

And then you can change the destination of your segue.

```
class ReplaceSegue: UIStoryboardSegue {

    override func perform() {
        let storyBoard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let newRootView = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "WelcomeViewController") as! WelcomeViewController
        sourceViewController.navigationController?.setViewControllers([newRootView], animated: true)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Yes, I need to set the view controller and should not do like "        self.window?.rootViewController = newRootView
" , I should do like "            self.setViewControllers([newRootView], animated: true)
" No need of using segues its working fine with the above mentioned line by me.

Comment: In the solution I presented you, you must override the rootView Segue linking your UINavigationViewController with you LoginViewController and copy-paste my code.

Answer (score -1):

First set user login bool true in NSUserDefults. when User is login Successfully.

```
UserDefaults.standard.set(true, forKey: "USERISLOGIN")
```

Now Open Appdelegate.swift -> didFinishLaunchingWithOptions Method:-

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

    if(UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "USERISLOGIN")){

                let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)

                let objLogoutVC = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "LogoutVC") as! LogoutVC
                let navigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: objLogoutVC)

                navigationController.navigationBar.isTranslucent = false
                navigationController.navigationBar.isHidden = true
                self.window?.rootViewController = navigationController
                self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
            }
     return true
}
```

Let me know if you needed any thing more.

Comment: "please don't suggest me to change the root view controller inside of didfinishlaunchingwithoptions method" x)

Comment: Indeed @Desdenova did not make this requirement clear enough.

Comment: I just edited the code block in the question. It's not my question obviously.